# How to structure data for an exercise app

Tags: ios, data-structures, structure, property-list

This seems like it should be so simple to create, but have had my gears turning on how exactly to set it up.  Basically I want to create a way for users to be able to save and update their exercise data as they use the app.  They will also be able to go back and review any day for their exercise results on that day.  I am currently considering using property lists for doing this, but is there a better way?

Example:

04-28-12
-- Exercise: Bench Press Set 1: 115 lbs x 12 reps Set 2: 125 x 10 reps Set 3: 130lbs x 8 reps

-- Exercise Squats Set 1: 215 x 10 reps Set 2...etc;

I really appreciate any input that you guys have on this!
Thanks.

Comment: This question is overly broad - consider breaking it down into smaller, bite-sized chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an `NSArray` which contains other arrays and an `NSDictionary` which can all be stored in a property list.

Then your structure would be like:

```
People (NSArray)
|
 --> Exercises (NSArray)
     |
      --> Sets (NSArray)
          |
           --> 0 (NSDictionary)
               |
                --> Weight (key): 115 (value)
               |
                --> Repetitions (key): 12 (value)
               |
                --> Type (key): 1 (value integer mapped to exercise type like Squats)
```

This can be pretty cumbersome though when you get a lot of data in this one property list, so you might want to consider using Core Data instead (http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Excellent suggestion of Core Data.  I am a rookie with that but it does make more sense.  Or possibly SQLite!  Thanks for your input

Comment: Glad to help!  Keep in mind that Core Date uses SQLite as a data store by default and handles all of the difficult SQL, etc for you